# google map in android display only grid 

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement Google Map but I am facing some problem with it.
The problem is that when I load my app it displays only the grid of the map (not an image of the map).

Here is my code... can anyone see the problem?

**Xml Main**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey=" api key"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.org.NewMap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".NewMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Java Class**

```
package info.org.NewMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
public class NewMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);      
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Second Java File**

```
package info.org.NewMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    private Context context;

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        this(defaultMarker);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mapOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mapOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
        this.populate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you giving correct map api key

Comment: yes u r right problem is api key..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used debug.keystore to get api key for map then it will not show map tiles when you launching signed the app with your own private keystore. 
Have you signed your app ?

To work map in signed app you must get api key from google using same keystore that you have used to sign the app(not debug.keystore).

Comment: Thanks dear, my problem is solve but i build api key from debug.keystore and it's working good.

Comment: +1 you r right if i am creating my api key from debug.keystore it working but when i create APK of my App it's creating problem so i have to create with my app keystore Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the following permissions to your application in your AndroidManifest.xml file

1. INTERNET
2. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
3. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Answer (score -1):

disable proxy server....map won't work if proxy server is enabled..

Comment: How could one do that and what does it have to do with anything?